# Java Bean Conventions

Tags: java, spring, servlets, javabeans, containers

One of the conventions of Java Beans is:

**The return type of the setter must be *void*.**

Or at least that's what most people say. My question is: does it really **HAVE TO** be void? I like to return **"this"** instead of **"void"** since I can chain methods together like this:

```
student.setName("Tom").setAge(15);
```

If I return "this" instead of "void", will there be any problem with Spring container or Servlet container or whatever makes use of Java Beans?

Comment: AFAIK, I don't think so.. You can safely do this.. But I had double check by running a sample bean.

Comment: you can simply implement a **builder pattern** but still leave **setter method** as convention.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the return type of a setter *must* be `void` in order for `java.beans.Introspector` to recognise it as a bean property and return a `PropertyDescriptor` for it.  APIs that just inspect the method names and argument types directly will work with non-void setters but anything that relies on the `Introspector` won't.

A good example of a workaround for this is the Amazon Web Services SDK, which provides both normal `public void setSomething` methods (to be a valid Java Bean) and also fluent `public X withSomething` methods that return `this`.

```
Student s = new Student().withName("Tom").withAge(15);
```

Answer (score -2):

To be sure, you can add another private method which return the object seted in your SET method and call this new method in **public void set()**

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. And it doesn't make much sense either.